# Open deeplink with parameters on android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, dynamic-links, android-universal-link

Following the intent format in https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/

```
intent:  
  HOST/URI-path  
  #Intent;  
    package=\[string\];  
    action=\[string\];  
    category=\[string\];  
    component=\[string\];  
    scheme=\[string\];  
  end;
```

We are sending HOST/URI-path: com.example/somePath?someVariableA=1

e.g. `intent://com.example/somePath?someVariableA=1#Intent;package=com.example;scheme=app;end;`

The android app receives data = com.example/somePath however we are missing someVariableA=1.

How can we get someVariableA=1?

Comment: If you get the whole string, then you can place it in the **Uri.parse(your_link)**  and then use the method **getQueryParameter** to pass the name of the key to. After that you should get the value

Comment: backend is sending it but android only sees `app://com.example/somePath`

Comment: Try replacing the "?" in the URI to "/"

Comment: do share the code snippet on how you're handling the deeplink and reading the deeplink data.

Answer (score 0):

When a deeplink is opened in an Android app, the parameters can be retrieved from the intent data URI.

Below is a way how you can achieve this in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    if (data != null) {
        List<String> parameters = data.getPathSegments();
        String paramA = "";

        if (parameters. Size() > 0) {
            paramA = parameters.get(0); // get first parameter
        }

        // Extracting query parameters
        String someVariableA = data.getQueryParameter("someVariableA"); 

        // Now you have your someVariableA
    }
}
```

In the code snippet above, we're getting the `Intent` that started the `Activity` and then extracting the data `Uri`. The `Uri` class has methods to parse the different parts of the URI, including the path segments and query parameters.

The `getQueryParameter(String key)` method can be used to retrieve the value of "someVariableA=1" by calling `data.getQueryParameter("someVariableA")`.

Remember, this code should be placed in the Activity that is started by the intent from the deeplink. In case the Activity might be started from elsewhere, you should add null checks as necessary to prevent `NullPointerException`s.